# Compute salt with known plaintext and hash?

Tags: security, passwords, hashing, plaintext, brute-force

I have the string that was used in a webapp with md5 hashing to come up with a hash. I also have the hash. But the md5 of the string doesn't match the hash, so I'm guessing there's a salt involved. Is there any software that can help me determine the salt?

Comment: Do you have just the hash, or a full authdb entry?

Comment: I just have the hash.

Answer (score 1):

In standard hashing functions (e.g., UNIX passwords in /etc/shadow) the salt is stored as part of the hash.

Pass the stored hash value as the salt and you should get the correct result.

The hashed password value in /etc/shadow is actually a $ delimited record. For example, we have this hash of the password 'blarg':

```
$1$KfcI/JTQ$b5VTf4i9Mnf6QFgLuVZNM0
```

There are three fields separated by $'s which are

1. The hash function (in this case '1', representing MD5)
2. The salt (which is 'KfcI/JTQ')
3. The hash value (which is 'b5VTf4i9Mnf6QFgLuVZNM0')

If you use mkpasswd several times the hash will change.

```
$ mkpasswd -m md5 blarg
$1$Gst52IWk$8ARVeSlpkcZOlyKV10Slu/

$ mkpasswd -m md5 blarg
$1$JeqRviA/$GnH/AvGnZEG9wLfJjiaAt1
```

However, by passing in the salt (i.e., the second field) from the hash value above we can match it against the original hash:

```
$ mkpasswd -m md5 -S KfcI/JTQ blarg
$1$KfcI/JTQ$b5VTf4i9Mnf6QFgLuVZNM0
```

You can also pass in the whole password hash (although omitting the hash function).

```
$ mkpasswd -m md5 -S KfcI/JTQ$b5VTf4i9Mnf6QFgLuVZNM0 blarg
$1$KfcI/JTQ$b5VTf4i9Mnf6QFgLuVZNM0
```

On Linux the hash type can be controlled in /etc/login.defs. Be very careful when changing this, you can completely lock yourself out of the system. I suggest reading the man page carefully specifically looking at the headings MD5_CRYPT_ENAB and ENCRYPT_METHOD.

Comment: In that case, the salt would be prefixed *before* the actual hash. And then the resulting string would not be a MD5 hash (like 32 hexadecimal digits), but something that is longer than that. And what do you mean with the last sentence?

Comment: I was going to add a comment to this, but what I wan't to say isn't very easy to write in the comment box. I'm adding another answer to be more thorough.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, this was from a webapp, that used their own custom-coded authentication system. Not Unix system passwords. These passwords were hashed by some PHP code before being stored in relational database. Thus, as Arjan said, I have a 32 digit string and the plaintext for it. Any method the salt can be computed from this, other than brute forcing all possible salts?

Comment: The salt should be included as part of the hash, or somewhere buried in the code is the single salt used for all of them.